# Analysis Services stored procedure performance

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, clrstoredprocedure

I'm writing a stored procedure in .NET to do some complex calculations that can't be written easily in pure MDX. The first problem I'm having is how to retrieve a set of data in a tabular form to pass to my calculation.

My code so far is written below. I would have thought that after we retrieve our value at position ***1, we would have all the data in memory to interact with. However, it seems that at position ***2, a Query Subcube is issued to the storage engine for each and every day in our range. This is devastating to performance.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there another method I can call to evaluate the set all at once?

```
// First get the date range that we'd like to calculate over.
// (These values are constant here for example only)
DateTime date = new DateTime(2012, 4, 1); 
int dateFrom = KeyFromDate(date.AddDays(-360));
int dateTo = KeyFromDate(date);

string dateRange = string.Format(
  "[Date].[Date].&[{0}]:[Date].[Date].&[{1}]", 
  dateFrom, 
  dateTo
);

Expression expression = new Expression(dateRange + "*[Measures].[My Measure]");
MDXValue value = expression.CalculateMdxObject(null); // ***1

foreach (var tuple in value.ToSet().Tuples)
{
  MDXValue tupleValue = MDXValue.FromTuple(tuple).ToInt32(); // ***2
}
```

Comment: How are you connecting to your cube to get the data?  Are you using ADOMD?  If so are you using ExecuteCellSet, ExecuteXmlReader, or somethignelse?

Comment: I'm writing an Analysis Services stored proc and the Expression class in the  Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdServer namespace [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdserver.expression.calculatemdxobject%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) connects to the cube. Adomd doesn't apply as it's for use in client apps.

Answer (score 0):

Run SQL Profiler, connect to analysis services, on tab "event selection" check "show all events" and select "get data from aggredations", "get data from cache", "query subsube" and "query subcube verbose".

First read this document http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17303 - see page 18 - in order to understand how "query subcube verbose" is working.

Then in Visual Studio (where you're debugging your procedure) in debug mode pass through line **1
and see in SQL Profiler what is queried in verbose - what measure group and what attributes.

Then pass through ***2 and see again in SQL Profiler in verbose events what is queried.

I believe that the set of attributes is different, so it may so happen that in ***1  it uses some aggregate, and in place ***2 when "value" is present in the tuple - there are no aggregate for this set of attributes, so instead of making "read from aggregations" once it makes "read from measure group cache" several times.

I can't tell more exactly cause I don't have your cube. Try to find this out by "query subcube verbose" events, and try to use BIDS Helper to create necessary aggregations manually (with specific set of attributes) - it may help.